# Javascript - sending html code in string via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, html-encode

How is the best way to send string from javascript to php with html tags inside? I'm trying, but all html tags disappear.

```
var ajaxData = '<div>some <b>text</b></div>';

jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ajaxData,
});
```

but in my php code var_dump($input); shows string like that: 'some text' instead

```
'<div>some <b>text</b></div>'
```

even this doesn't work

```
htmlspecialchars(urldecode($input));
```

Comment: Please explain in brief what you want to do

Comment: replace `data: ajaxData` with something like this
`data: {'ad': ajaxData}`

Comment: You shouldn't be using `urldecode` on `$input` either if it comes from one of the request superglobals.

Comment: Have you used json.stringify

Answer (score 1):

did you tried to view source?
var_dump will output the variable as is, so if it contains HTML the browser will parse it and you won't see the HTML part (only in view source).

try to escape it before using var_dump.

```
var_dump(htmlspecialchars($input));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at the page source for the page where you're doing the `var_dump`? I suspect your browser is actually parsing the `div` and `b` tags, so the HTML is not showing up in the text...